# What Does No such interface supported Mean

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am getting an exception on my server side code, which is serving up a silverlight app,

> Win32Exception - No such interface supported

Our server side C# code starts up a separate process for a short task because of a third party dll not being thread safe. So the error above occurs in part of the code like this,

```
Process process = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

processStartInfo.FileName = 
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin", "PreviewGenerator.exe");

process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

process.Start(); // THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS
process.WaitForExit();
```

The PreviewGenerator.exe process does not start when it is not working, the exception occurs where the comment is above.

UPDATE:

I have run process monitor on the IIS server when the issue occurs. This shows that the w3wp process does this,

```
Thread Create
Access the file PreviewGenerator.exe
Hive unloaded (this is the registry)
Thread Exit
```

And it does this before calling the other process. If I compare this with a the process monitor log when it is working it does this,

```
Thread Create
Access the file PreviewGenerator.exe
Process Start
Does heaps of stuff with PreviewGenerator.exe including reading / writing / registry, etc.
Process Exit
Hive unloaded
Thread Exit
```

But process monitor does not show any information as to why the first case doesn't work.

Is there a way I can see why the thread exits prematurely?

Also I think this problem relates to when my server is being loaded up more, and much more memory is being used. How can I prove this?

Comment: Most likely error pops up from "PreviewGenerator.exe" operation, but you just need to debug and provide an exact line of code an exception is thrown at.

Comment: Will be very hard to answer. Try adding the full error info. Also, something has changed. Find out what. Recent updates etc.

Comment: I have updated based on your responses.

Comment: What kind of app is your PreviewGenerator.exe?

Comment: A C# console application. It calls a third party DLL called GhostScript. It uses DLLImport to call into the unmanaged DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best thing to do was to create a separate app pool for my application in IIS and set an upper limit for the amount of RAM it could use. Also I found it useful to turn on the 'Generate Recycle Event Log Entry' items under the app pool settings.

You can then go to the system event log and filter out the items with a source of 'WAS' to understand what is going on in the app pools, when they are restarting and when they stop from being idle etc.

I think the main problem in our case is that the IIS box was running out of memory. Tuning the app pools and adding some extra RAM seems to have solved it.

Comment: Thank you, a great answer which helped me with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, I used
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
and that fixed it for me.

http://www.progtown.com/topic31343-process-start-processstartinfo-startinfo.html